# Pandoc cannot parse equation with a fraction

Tags: equations, conversion, pandoc

Pandoc is having a lot of trouble with this:

```
> pandoc -f latex -t html -s -o test2.html
$$
\frac{1}{2}
$$
```

Outputs:

```
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math '\frac{1}{1}', rendering as TeX
```

LaTeX compiles it just fine, of course. It seems ridiculous that pandoc would not be able to handle this.

Comment: Well there is some truth in the error message. If it is trying to parse this as tex, then frac is not defined. Tex uses a different syntax for fractions. So you might need more options for pandoc (on a tablet right now so cannot test)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Beside that $$...$$ syntax is not recommended in LaTeX, it is unclear what are you doing really.

There are not an input latex file in the command line, but guessing that is

```
$$
\frac{1}{2}
$$
```

Saving this  as  `test.tex`, then:

```
pandoc -f latex -t html  test.tex
```

Producing this output:

```
<p><br /><span class="math display">$$\frac{1}{2}$$</span><br /></p>
```

Adding  `-s -o test.html` only will save this inside a complete XHTML file, but of course, without rendering in any way.

Guessing that you want really is render the math display class with Mathjax in a browser, then you should run:

```
pandoc -f latex  --mathjax  -t html test.tex -s -o test.html

firefox test.html
```

Output in Firefox:

[image: mwe]

Comment: That's precisely it! I was confused because the simple equations seemed to render just fine. I missed that it was not using mathjax to render.

Answer (score 8):

Including the `--mathjax` flag fixed this:

> The default is to render TeX math as far as possible using Unicode characters. Formulas are put inside a span with class="math", so that they may be styled differently from the surrounding text if needed. However, this gives acceptable results only for basic math, usually you will want to use --mathjax or another of the following options.

https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math-rendering-in-html